# Building Tree structure Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, treeview

I am trying to build tree structure using angular 2 with a basic parent-child concept.

**component.html template looks like below:**

```
<li class="nav-item " *ngFor="let dir of directories">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        <span class="title">{{ dir.name }}</span>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let file of directories.child">
        <li class="nav-item  ">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
                <span class="title">{{file.name}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <navigation-bar [directories]="dir.child"></navigation-bar>
     </ul>
</li>
```

**component.ts file :**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'navigation-bar',
    templateUrl: './app/home/navigationBar.component.html',    
})

export class NavigationBarComponent {
    @Input() directories: Array<Tree>;      
}

export class Tree{
    directories: any;
    constructor()
    {
        this.directories = [
        {
            name: 'parent1',
            child: [{
                name: 'child1',
                child: []
            },
            {
                name: 'child2',
                child: []
            }]
        },
        {
            name: 'parent2',
            child: {
                name: 'child1',
                child: []
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'parent2',
            child: [{
                name: 'child1',
                child: []
            },
            {
                name: 'child2',
                child: []
            }]
        }];
    }    
}
```

But it always renders the parent nodes only.
Don't know where I am doing wrong! I am almost blank now. Any suggestion, please...

Comment: put dir.child instead of directories.child in the second ngFor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
<ul class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let file of directories.child">
```

with

```
<ul class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let file of dir.child">
```

Comment: @VigneshwaranMarkandan, Glad to here that ,Will you please also accept the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your second loop in html, You iterate through directories. You have to iterate through the parent like this

`<ul class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let file of dir.child">`